# Alinhar o conteúdo da div ao centro, mas os textos ficarem na esquerda

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho esse código.  Eu quero que o texto continue centralizado na div, mas com o alinhamento na esquerda.
Eu coloquei um text-align:left, mas o texto continua centralizado.

```
<div style="
width:1000px;
height:400px;
background:red;

display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
text-align: left;"
>
 <h1>Texto 1</h1>
 <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero que fique assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, crie uma div principal que centralize o conteúdo filho com `text-align: center`. Depois crie uma div filho que use `display: inline-block` para se adaptar à largura de seus filhos e `text-align: left` para fazer com que o conteúdo fique alinhado à esquerda.

```html
<div style="
width:1000px;
height:400px;
background:red;

display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
text-align: left;">

<div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">
  <h1>Texto 1</h1>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta. se tirar o align-items o conteudo nao vai ficar mais centralizado.

Comment: @HeberLeonard Agora sim. Editado, explicado e funcionando